# How to make an ajax loaded table work with keyboard navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, tabindex

So I have had an issue with web pages where we use ajax to load the rows into a table. To make the rows focusable we put a tabindex="0" on each  which works fine. The problem is that there is a link under the table (for exporting to excel) that will always get tab focus before it moves on to the first row of the table which is a bit annoying for the user.

The browser (Chrome) does not seem to tab through each element on the screen in the order they are in the dom but some other order based on time the object was added to the dom. Does anyone have any good suggestions how to do this? The link have tabindex="0" as well but I have also tried setting e.g the tabindex of the link to some very high number in case the browser tabbed through all 0 before moving to the next higher number - but if I do this the link under stops being focusable at all for some reason.

Comment: If the table data is loading after the focus has been defined then it sounds like you need to explicitly re-focus after the data loads.  Have you tried triggering a `focus` event on the element you want to focus?

Comment: Well the user goes into a page, and the table rows are dynamically loaded after so the user then hits TAB on the keyboard (site needs WCAG compliance), the problem is that the first thing it tabs to is the link under the table, not the first row. Actually if there are buttons above the table those will first get focus, then it jumps to the link on the bottom of the page, and then next tab moves it to the first row of the table. Its just not very user friendly.